# I am trying to add data fetched from an API in chart.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to add data fetched from an API in chart.js, I am able to fetch data from an API but I am having an issue adding those fetched data to the chart.js array only the first data add up to the [data] array of chart.js and not the second element of the same array, it seems like data fetched from the API don't get stored in one array.

Below is the code I am using

```js
        function tip(){
              fetch(url)
              .then((res) => res.json())
              .then((data) => data.pages.map((obj)=>{
                var arr = [];
// append new value to the array
    arr.push(`${obj.visits}`);
              console.log(arr);
              
            
                 })
                
                );
                var ctx = document.getElementById('mychartst').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ['Red','new', 'yellow'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    data: arr,//here only the first data of an array , shows up and not the other of obj.visit Expected outcome should be [535,512] which is arr.
                    backgroundColor: [
                        
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        })
                
               


            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<button class="stats" onclick="tip();">CLick to see stats</button>

<canvas id="mychartst"></canvas>


<!-- Expect outcome should be var arr=[535,512]-->
```

```
//Here is the response format
{
    "pages": [ 
                 { "visits": 535, "uniqueVisits": 503 }, 
                 { "visits": 512, "uniqueVisits": 437 } 
             ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to S.O ! ! Can you post the ```response``` in json. Since the ```url``` in the snippet is not defined.

Comment: Ya sure, here is the respnse from the json:

Comment: "pages": [
    {
      "visits": 535,
      "uniqueVisits": 503
    },
    {
      "visits": 512,
      "uniqueVisits": 437
    }
  ],

Comment: You would like to put  that two object in the array into 1 array?

Comment: Yes, I want to add the two object values in an array by name [data] of the chart.js.

Comment: You can update your expected outcome in the question so that we can know clearly.

Comment: I have updated the outcome in the question, basically, I want the {visits} data I am getting from the fetch API to output in the chart.js  data like this data: [ visits[0], visits[1],...] or data:[535,512,..]